# How to help my 8-year-old son who is not potty trained whatsoever?

Tags: middle-childhood, encopresis

My 8-year-old son has regressed in his potty training. He was fully potty trained when he was 4 or 5, then slowly stopped. Now he won't use the bathroom at all.

He's in second grade and has to wear diapers to school. Even kids making fun of him at school didn't push him to try to potty train again. We have seen doctors, specialists and a therapist. Nothing has helped.

The only thing the specialist did was put him in hospital and clean his intestines of all poop by doing a complete flush out of his system. The doctors just said he was being lazy and they couldn't find anything wrong in x-rays either. We even had him tested for autism and ADHD, but he doesn't have anything.

My son says he can't help it, but the doctors keep telling me that nothing was wrong with him. Punishment doesn't work. Reward charts and bribery don't do anything.

I'm going crazy. I just want him out of diapers already. He's going into 3rd grade soon. Is he ever going to be out of diapers? Is there a reason why he does it?

Another thing that the doctors ignore is how many times a day he poops and the fact his poop looks like baby poop. It doesn't come out as turds or logs.

Comment: We understand that this is a big problem, but your post doesn't have an actual question, so we can't answer it. If you can edit your post to put a specific question at the end (not just "any advice?") then we can try to help. However bear in mind that we're not doctors  and can't give medical advice.

Comment: I'm not a doctor, but I was wondering what powered the decision to put him back on diapers? Has he been having accidents? Has your son been evaluated for Encopresis (https://kidshealth.org/en/parents/encopresis.html)?  Have you see a gastroenterologist? The other thing I can think of is food intolerances or Crohn's that causes frequent loose stools. It's embarrassing to some kids to have to poop at school.

Comment: Please see tag "encopresis" for a lot of similar problems and answers.